# Как из символа char '2' получить int == 2 ? (си)

Tags: c, массивы, char, калькулятор

Имеется массив типа char. В нем такая запись "2*3". При попытке умножения берет номер символа 2 и 3, как сделать, чтобы при умножении читались именно сами числа?

вот код прототипа функции:

```
char calc (int a, int b, char oper)
{   char p;
    switch(oper)
    {
    case '*': p = a*b; break;
    case '/': p = a/b; break;
    case '+': p = a+b; break;
    case '-': p = a-b; break;
    }
  return (p);
}
```

Comment: Именно из **символа**? `p-'0'`. Например, `'2'-'0'==2`.

Comment: вообще есть функции вроде atoi, они сразу число преобразуют. А если одну цифру, то вычесть 0x30 (код нуля)

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы из массива символов "2*3" получить символ 6.

Answer (score 0):

Вот программка для вычисления того что вам нужно (я так думаю). Ввдите ей 2*3 и получите 6, 55/11 - получите 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, p;
    char c;
    if (scanf("%d%c%d", &a, &c, &b) == 3) {
        switch (c) {
            case '*':
                p = a * b;
                break;
            case '/':
                p = a / b;
                break;
            case '+':
                p = a + b;
                break;
            case '-':
                p = a - b;
                break;
            }
        printf("Result = %d\n", p);
        }
    }
```